# django-templates For 31 times?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a simple calendar in html but I can not create FOR 31 times

Django-Views:

```python
def calendar(request):
    try:
        tvserie = Tvserie.objects.order_by('-date_next_episode')
        return render_to_response('calendar.html',{'tvserie':tvserie})
    except:
        return render_to_response('error_page.html')
```

Django-Template:

```html
<table border="1">
  {% for 0 in 31 %}
    <tr>
    {% if forloop.counter == tvserie.date_next_episode.day %}
      <td>
        {{tvserie.date_next_episode.day}}
        {{tvserie.network}}<br>
        {{tvserie.number_next_episode}} {{tvserie.title}}<br>
        "{{tvserie.title_next_episode}}"<br>
      </td>
    {% else %}
      <td>
        {{forloop.counter}}
      </td>
    {% endif %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom template filter to create a range in the following way:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_range(val):
    return range(val)
```

Then, you should replace this:

```
{% for 0 in 31 %}
```

With this:

```
{% for day in 31|get_range %}
```

It creates a 31 items range and iterates over it.

Comment: Django doesn't have a built-in `get_range` template filter. If you refer to a specific custom filter implementation, please provide it

Comment: How do I create get_range?

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev, you're right of course. Forgot I had it implemented and that it doesn't come out of the box with Django.. Updated the answer with the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

One way is use `custom tag` or simply this may help you.

```
{% for i in "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx#31 times" %}
    {{ forloop.counter0 }}
{% endfor %}
```